# Grappling training for a striker

Tags: training, grappling, self-training, striking

I've trained in Chun Kuk Do for years (still pursuing my black belt) and I want to cross train with grappling as to be balanced for real-world combat. My current goal is to get my black belt in this system (while cross training grappling on the side) and then to get my black belts in BJJ and Krav Maga.

So anyhow, here's my question: How best should I pursue grappling training to build on my previous training as a striker. I fully realize the need for grappling/ground training, I'm not asking about the pros/cons of "grappling vs. striking". How best can I best build on the striking training I've learned to learning/becoming skilled at ground fighting? Any ideas?

Comment: One clarification - You say you've been training "years", how many years? While wanting to cross train is admirable, if you have been training extensively in CKD and still have not achieved BB, why would you want to mix in more stuff? When was the last time you were in "real world combat" where grappling would have made a difference?

Answer (score 8):

Stop planning your eventual wall of black belts and go get a blue belt in BJJ or a brown belt in judo or join a SAMBO school or join a wrestling club. Worry about integrating your grappling into your striking after you have some grappling skill.

Try a class at each of the grappling schools in your area, pick the one with the highest quality teachers and best schedule and most copious sparring, and train. You'll figure out how to build it into your existing training without any extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Greco-Roman wrestling is always a good option that isn't mentioned nearly enough. I mention it because there's bound to be a club close to you, no matter where you are in the world.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start with a mixture of striking and grappling you should go to an MMA school where this is likely to happen but your grappling will develop slower than by joining a grappling school.

On the other hand you could join: BJJ, Sambo, Wrestling or Judo depending on what you're more interested in ground work or throws. After gaining some skill you can try mixing up striking with grappling either with a training partner/friend or in some MMA training context.

Answer (score -1):

This is from fa jing, grappler focused combat.  Never grapple a seasoned grappler that's always his game.  But a dim mak stun or knockout will set up a grapple for your style. Stick with your strengths.  Also very important, pick an object you see a lot.  Every time you see it in your peripheral vision as fast as you possibly can do a silent one syllable shout.  This let's you react to things instantly if practiced well.  "Its the only way to defeat a grappler".